# scrape url, username and like count from instagram post from a given hashtag using selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, instagram

I'm currently working on a web scraping project using Selenium and BeautifulSoup to extract post data from Instagram based on a hashtag. However, when running my code, it returns 0 posts. Here's what I have done so far:

1. Set up the Selenium webdriver and initialized it.
2. Navigated to the Instagram hashtag page using the provided hashtag.
3. Added the session ID cookie to the webdriver.
4. Refreshed the page to apply the session ID cookie.
5. Waited for the page to load.
6. Extracted the HTML content and parsed it using BeautifulSoup.
7. Located the main section of the page.
8. Extracted post URLs, usernames, and likes by iterating through the post elements.
9. Added posts with more than 1000 likes to the post_data list.

However, despite following these steps, I'm getting 0 posts in the extracted data. Can you please advise on what I might be doing wrong or suggest an alternative approach to retrieve the desired post data? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
from json.tool import main
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pprint import pprint
from selenium_stealth import stealth
import json
import time


def setup_webdriver(webdriver_path):
    """Creates a new Chrome webdriver instance using Service."""
    service = Service(webdriver_path)
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument(
        f'--user-data-dir=/Users/ronnydiaz/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default')
    options.add_argument("start-maximized")
    options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
    options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
    return webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)


def get_post_data(driver, hashtag):
    """Gets the post data for the given hashtag."""
    session_id = '37384277226%3AeIYsLt3LDOCNoW%3A3%3AAYfZbBm3JLc1fAaagWhF2ly0ZoruzLUCrKJMwRVRcQ'
    driver.get(f"https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/{hashtag}/")
    driver.add_cookie({'name': 'sessionid', 'value': session_id,
                       'domain': '.instagram.com'})

    # Get cookie details with named cookie 'session_id'
    print(driver.get_cookie("session_id"))

    # Refresh the page to apply the session ID cookie
    driver.refresh()

    # Wait for the page to load and post elements to be present
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    post_elements = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(
        (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a[href*="/p/"]')))

    print(f"Attempting: {driver.current_url}")
    if "login" in driver.current_url:
        print("Failed/ redir to login")
        return []

    # Extract the HTML content
    html_content = driver.page_source

    # Parse the HTML content using BeautifulSoup
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'html.parser')

    main_section = soup.find('main')
    print(main_section)

    # Extract post URLs, usernames, and likes
    post_data = []
    post_elements = main_section.select('a[href*="/p/"]')
    for post_element in post_elements:
        post_url = post_element['href']
        username_element = post_element.find_next('span')
        username = username_element.text if username_element else ''
        likes_element = post_element.find_next('span', class_='zV_Nj')
        likes_count = int(likes_element.text.replace(
            ',', '')) if likes_element else 0
        if likes_count > 1000:
            post_data.append({
                'post_url': f"https://www.instagram.com{post_url}",
                'username': username,
                'likes': likes_count
            })

    return post_data


def save_post_data(post_data, filename):
    """Saves the post data to a JSON file."""
    with open(filename, 'w') as file:
        json.dump(post_data, file, indent=4)
    print(f"Total posts: {len(post_data)}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Set up the webdriver
    webdriver_path = '/usr/local/bin/chromedriver'
    driver = setup_webdriver(webdriver_path)

    # Get the post data for the hashtag 'fitness'
    hashtag = 'health'
    post_data = get_post_data(driver, hashtag)

    # Save the post data to a JSON file
    filename = 'post_data.json'
    save_post_data(post_data, filename)

    # Close the browser
    driver.quit()
```